# Attempting to create SQL Server resource using managed identity in a runbook gives forbidden result

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-managed-identity, azure-runbook

I'm trying to create an Azure SQL Server in a PowerShell runbook. I am using a managed identity to which I have assigned contributor role to the subscription I'm trying to create it in.

This is the code line:

```
New-AzSqlServer -ResourceGroupName $rgName -ServerName $newServerName -Location $location -AssignIdentity -EnableActiveDirectoryOnlyAuthentication -ExternalAdminName $adminAccount
```

I am getting this response:

> Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden'

Prior to the offending line I am connecting as follows:

```
Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process
$context = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity -AccountId "<account-client-id>").context 
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
$context = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $context.Subscription -DefaultProfile $context
```

I used to have a simpler version but after checking with Microsoft docs, that was the recommended way to do it. When it connects everything seems to be in its place, tenant, subscription, managed identity client id...

Comment: As mentioned in the existing answer, the managed identity does not have permission to get the objectid of the `ExternalAdminName`. You could just specify the `ExternalAdminSID` param as well. Then you don't need extra permission.

Comment: ExternalAdminSID  should is just the objectID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have one managed identity named **`srimanaged`** assigned with **Contributor** role under subscription like this:

[image]

Now, I added this **managed identity** under my automation account:

[image]

When I ran your code in my environment, I got **same error** like this:

```
Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process
$context = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity -AccountId "<account-client-id>").context 
$subscriptionId = "subId"
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
$context = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $context.Subscription -DefaultProfile $context

$rgName = "Sri"
$newServerName = "sqlserver0711"
$location = "Central US"
$adminAccount = "Testuser"
New-AzSqlServer -ResourceGroupName $rgName -ServerName $newServerName -ServerVersion "12.0" -Location $location -AssignIdentity -EnableActiveDirectoryOnlyAuthentication -ExternalAdminName $adminAccount
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **resolve** the error, try assigning **`User Administrator`** role to the **managed identity** under your directory:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Microsoft Entra ID -> Roles and administrators -> All roles -> Select 'User Administrator' -> Add assignment*

[image]

When I ran **same script** again after assigning that role, I got **response** like this:

```
Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process
$context = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity -AccountId "<account-client-id>").context 
$subscriptionId = "subId"
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
$context = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $context.Subscription -DefaultProfile $context

$rgName = "Sri"
$newServerName = "sqlserver0711"
$location = "Central US"
$adminAccount = "Testuser"
New-AzSqlServer -ResourceGroupName $rgName -ServerName $newServerName -ServerVersion "12.0" -Location $location -AssignIdentity -EnableActiveDirectoryOnlyAuthentication -ExternalAdminName $adminAccount
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in Portal where SQL Server **created** successfully with below properties:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

If you prefer **least privileges**, you can create **custom** directory role by allowing specific permissions to read the users. Refer this **[MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/role-based-access-control/custom-create)** for creating custom role in Microsoft Entra ID.

Alternatively, try assigning **`Directory Reader`** role to the managed identity instead of assigning *User Administrator* role.

Comment: `User Admin` is too much. The principal running the deployment just need read permission.

Comment: That's right, we wouldn't want to have a user with such privileges, but worst case scenario we will provide one with them. We will try the provided options. Thank you so much for taking the time!!!

Comment: @sridevi I am not getting your result, I am getting a 500 error from the server, what could be happening? I added the mentioned permissions.

Comment: Could you **confirm** whether you added role to the **user** assigned managed identity that is attached to automation account or not? Are you using same PowerShell script that I mentioned in my answer? If possible, can you add those error and role assigned snips from Portal by editing your new question?