# Can't connect to managed identity with User Administrator role

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-managed-identity, azure-runbook

After applying the solution provided in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77438816/attempting-to-create-sql-server-resource-using-managed-identity-in-a-runbook-giv), which was basically adding User Administrator role to the managed identity I am using, I am getting the following error when connecting to the managed identity, which didn't happen before:

Unable to acquire token for tenant 'organizations' with error 'ManagedIdentityCredential authentication failed: Internal Server Error occured with identity passed!

```
Status: 500 (Internal Server Error)
   

Content:
   

Headers:

Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

Date: Tue, 14 Nov 2023 12:34:53 GMT

Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0


See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/managedidentitycredential/troubleshoot'
ManagedIdentityCredential authentication failed: Internal Server Error occured with identity passed!

Status: 500 (Internal Server Error)



Content:


Headers:

Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

Date: Tue, 14 Nov 2023 12:34:53 GMT

Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0


See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/managedidentitycredential/troubleshoot
Run Connect-AzAccount to login.
```

**UPDATE**
Here's the automation account identity section:
[image]

Here's the contributor role:
[image]

Here's the user administrator role:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The error might occur if you **missed** adding that user-assigned managed
> identity in your automation account, that you are specifying in **`AccountId`** parameter.

I have one managed identity with **`Contributor`** role under subscription:

[image]

Now, I added **User Administrator** directory role to that user-assigned managed identity like this:

[image]

Initially, I have **not added** any user assigned managed identity in automation account as below:

[image]

When I ran below script to create SQL server by connecting via user assigned managed identity, I got **same error** as below:

```
Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process
$context = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity -AccountId "<account-client-id>").context 
$subscriptionId = "subId"
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
$context = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $context.Subscription -DefaultProfile $context

$rgName = "Sri"
$newServerName = "sqlserver151123"
$location = "Central US"
$adminAccount = "Testuser"
New-AzSqlServer -ResourceGroupName $rgName -ServerName $newServerName -ServerVersion "12.0" -Location $location -AssignIdentity -EnableActiveDirectoryOnlyAuthentication -ExternalAdminName $adminAccount
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **resolve** the error, make sure to add the user-assigned managed identity that you are specifying in **`AccountId`** under the automation account like this:

[image]

When I ran the same script again now, I got **response** successfully as below:

```
Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process
$context = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity -AccountId "<account-client-id>").context 
$subscriptionId = "subId"
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
$context = Set-AzContext -SubscriptionName $context.Subscription -DefaultProfile $context

$rgName = "Sri"
$newServerName = "sqlserver151123"
$location = "Central US"
$adminAccount = "Testuser"
New-AzSqlServer -ResourceGroupName $rgName -ServerName $newServerName -ServerVersion "12.0" -Location $location -AssignIdentity -EnableActiveDirectoryOnlyAuthentication -ExternalAdminName $adminAccount
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in Portal where SQL server created successfully with below properties:

[image]

Comment: I have indeed added the managed identity to the automation account, so I'm at a loss here. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Could you include that screenshot from your Portal by editing your question? Please check whether it's the same user-assigned managed identity or not by checking client ID of managed identity with `AccountId` parameter value.

Comment: Updated, let me know if i can provide any more info

Comment: Could you check whether you are passing **client Id** of `dbbackup` identity in `AccountId` parameter of your Automation powershell script or not?

Comment: Yes, I'm passing the correct client id

Comment: If you remove user administrator role, are you able to connect using user-assigned managed identity?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255947/discussion-between-sridevi-and-victor).

Comment: For future reference: the side issue was that I had re-created the same managed identity multiple times with the same name, and it was causing issues.